# PHP fsockopen help required

Tags: php, curl, fsockopen, cloudflare

I was trying to work on cloudflare api and I have found this in their documentation. Unfortunately I have no Idea how I can use this in fsockopen or through curl. Here is the example of POST Request. I just need to know how I can make a request with below data as POST using curl or fsockopen

```
curl https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html 
-d 'a=cache_lvl' \
-d 'tkn=8afbe6dea02407989af4dd4c97bb6e25' \
-d 'email=sample@example.com' \
-d 'z=example.com' \
-d 'v=agg'
```

Here is the link to cloudflare
https://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html#s4.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

// handling of -d curl parameter is here.
$param = array(
    'a' => 'cache_lvl',
    'tkn' => '8afbe6dea02407989af4dd4c97bb6e25',
    'email' => 'sample@example.com',
    'z' => 'ex'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($param));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print $result;
```

Comment: Thanks alot It worked with a few changes as per my needs but thanks again for showing me the way.